# How can I get the nearest rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I'm trying to build a thumbnail of some gallery (5 thumbnails showing). How can I get my mysql to display 5 thumbnails, the middle thumbnail will be the image blown up, and the two on the left of the middle will be previous images, and the two other images on the right of the middle will be 2 more images after.

EDIT

---

I know how to easily get 5 thumbnails with something like this

```
$sqlThumb = mysql_query("SELECT iID,thumbnails,userID FROM images WHERE userID = ".$_SESSION['userID']." ORDER BY iID ASC LIMIT 1,5");
```

But the thing is, I dont have a consistent id (meaning, there will be deleting and inserting). It is based on the images that the user has.

```
iID            userID 
-----          --------
1              5
2              4
3              4
4              5
5              5
6              5
10             5
11             5
12             5
```

So if a user clicks an image which shoes iID number 5, the thumbnail should show like this in order, 1,4,5,6,10.

However, also if a user clicks on thumbnail number 10, the thumbnail should show: 5,6,10,11,12.

Comment: I have updated my post, to clarify my question

Comment: have you tried my query .if want to get only from particular user just add **AND  userID = ".$_SESSION['userID']."** in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$offset = $current_id-3;

 (SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id < '$current_id'    limit '$offset',2 )
 union( SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id = '$current_id') 
 union (SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id > '$current_id' limit 2)
```

Comment: by the looks of this query, you're subtracting $current_id by 3?

Comment: @andewwliu: yes, off course you need to find offset to get previous two records.why do you figured any bugs in query. any none relevant results

Comment: I'm trying to work. but am I supposed to do this with `mysql_query(" (SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id < '$current_id'    limit '$offset',2 )
 union( SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id = '$current_id') 
 union (SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id > '$current_id' limit 2)");?`

Comment: @andrewliu: don't understand what you asking.but i test that query that works before posting my answer.just replace table name correct column names then add any condition in where clauss if you wish.Is that helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but the idea is to have an attribute called `row_number`. You will get the image you want by the id and the two last and the two next by the row number.

```
SELECT iID,thumbnail FROM image_collection,
   (SELECT iID, thumbnail, row_number
   FROM
      (SELECT iID,thumbnail,
      @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
      FROM image
      WHERE userID = 5
      ORDER BY iID) as image_collection
   WHERE s_image.iID = 10) as image_selected
WHERE image_collection.row_number BETWEEN image_selected.row_number - 2 AND image_selected.row_number + 2
```

I don't tested it because I don't have MySQL running, but I see how to put the row number here: [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (doesn't include any subtraction):

```
$id = 5;
$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];

$sqlThumb = mysql_query("
SELECT iID FROM images WHERE userID = ".$user_id." AND iID = ".$id."
  UNION (SELECT iID FROM images WHERE userID = ".$user_id." AND iID < ".$id." ORDER BY iID DESC LIMIT 2) 
  UNION (SELECT iID FROM images WHERE userID = ".$user_id." AND iID > ".$id." ORDER BY iID ASC LIMIT 2) 
  ORDER BY iID ASC")
```

Comment: :you did n't used offset in ** UNION (SELECT iID FROM images WHERE userID = ".$user_id." AND iID < ".$id." ORDER BY iID ASC LIMIT 2)** which means your query will fail to get nearest previous.for ex :1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. consider 6 as current id .your query will select 1,2 .not 4,5

Comment: @gowri: Thanks for noting this, should be `ORDER BY iID *DESC*` there. I've edited answer and it works OK.

Comment: still you wrong desc will change the order so the result will be 5,4,6,7,8. so you can't get correct order using this query

Comment: @gowri: you aren't right, `ORDER BY iID ASC` in last line applies to results from all three subqueries, so final result will be sorted properly (4,5,6,7,8 in this case).

Comment: :yes i missed that part. let see OP's response