# Displaying 11 consecutive rows from a query where middle row contains a variable

Tags: php, sql, pagination

On my web page, there is a variable called `$submission`.  I would like to display exactly 11 rows from the query below: the row where `$submission` equals `$row["title"]`, 5 rows above it, and 5 rows below it.  All ranked by `points` descending.

How can I do this?

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
             FROM submission 
         ORDER BY points DESC"; 


$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array();

$count=1;

echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


    echo '<tr >';

    echo '<td>'.$count++.'.</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename1">'.$row["title"].'</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename2"><div class="pointlink2">'.number_format($row["points"]).'</div></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Does your schema permit duplicate "title" values?

Comment: Do you have a specific "midpoint" point value that you want results around? Is that the value of $submission?

Comment: @ rdlowery the midpoint is where $submission equals the title.  They're both text.

Comment: +1 There is some subtlety here if several `submission` records share the same value for `points`.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184965/how-can-i-get-the-nearest-rows-in-mysql (no accepted answer there, but better search title).

Comment: consider using DataTables + Twitter Bootstrap due to implement great tables with pagination. Check this out http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky if several rows share the same value for "points":

```
points | title | submissionid
------ + ----- + ------------
    ...
   50  | 'foo' | ABCD01234     <-- If (50, 'foo') is the "midpoint" record,
   50  | 'bar' | EF7654321     <-- does (50, 'bar') come before or after?
    ...
```

In this case, we need to impose an order.  For convenience we're going to order by "points" descending and then "title" descending.

Assuming your "midpoint record" has a points value of '@points' and a title '@title', we'll say the records that come "before" the midpoint are those records whose (points, title) > (@points, @title).  Similarly, those records "after" the midpoint have their (points, title) < (@points, @title).

Putting it together, we have:

```
-- First, initialize user variables with the points and
-- title of our midpoint (including midpoint)
--
SELECT @title := title,
       @points := points
  FROM submission
 WHERE title = ?          -- bind your $submission variable bere
 LIMIT 1;

-- Now, select six records greater than or equal to our
-- midpoint.
--
  SELECT title, points, submissionid
        FROM (  SELECT title, points, submissionid
                  FROM submission
                 WHERE (points, title) >= (@points, @title)
              ORDER BY points ASC, title ASC
                 LIMIT 6) gte
-- and UNION those records with five records less than
-- our midpoint
--
   UNION
  SELECT title, points, submissionid
        FROM (  SELECT title, points, submissionid
                  FROM submission
                 WHERE (points, title) < (@points, @title)
              ORDER BY points DESC, title DESC
                 LIMIT 5) lt
-- Finally sort the result set
--
ORDER BY points DESC, title DESC
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?  Thanks.

Comment: @John, a little more specific about which part?

Comment: @ pilcrow How could I combine all this into one query?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `UNION`

```
(
    SELECT title, points, submissionid
    FROM submission
    WHERE points < (SELECT points FROM submission WHERE title = <row_title> LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5
)UNION(
    SELECT title, points, submissionid
    FROM submission
    WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM submission WHERE title = <row_title> LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 5
) ORDER BY points DESC
```

I haven't tested it, but this is the gist of it. You will get 10 records (or less), you'll have to figure out in PHP which records should go above your `$submission` and which below, since if you get 9 records you wont know if 4 are higher, or 5.

Alternatively you could just do it with 2 queries of course >_>

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    title, points, submissionid
FROM
    submission 
WHERE 
    ROWID >= (SELECT ROWID FROM submission WHERE ..... ORDER BY points DESC) - 5
AND
    ROWID <= (SELECT ROWID FROM submission WHERE ..... ORDER BY points DESC) + 5
ORDER BY 
    points DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its simplest to just do 2 queries against the database, but you could do it in PHP:

```
$entryFound = false;
$counter = 0;
$priorEntries = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $rowHtml = '<tr >';
    $rowHtml .=  '<td>'.$count++.'.</td>';
    $rowHtml .= '<td class="sitename1">'.$row["title"].'</td>';
    $rowHtml .= '<td class="sitename2"><div class="pointlink2">'.number_format($row["points"]).'</div></td>';
    $rowHtml .= '</tr>';

    if ($entryFound) {
            if ($counter < 5) {
                $counter++;
                echo $rowHtml;
            }
    } else {            
            array_unshift($priorEntries, $rowHtml); 
            if (strcmp($row["title"], $submission) == 0) {
                echo implode(array_reverse($priorEntries));
                $entryFound = true;
            }   
    array_splice($priorEntries, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  Am I supposed to leave the query the same?

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea.  What didn't work for you?  I had forgotten a semicolon on the array_splice($priorEntries, 5); line, however, I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following might do what you are asking. It will run the query and start reading records from the result set up until it finds the *first* occurrence of a record with a title that equals the `$submission` variable that you have (if I understand it correctly the primary key of your table is the submissionid and the title is a simple field - i.e. you do not have a unique key on it, so there may be more than one records with the same title).

After it finds that first record it will read 5 more records and stop. Then it will provide you with the part of the array of records that you wish to print and finally it will print it.

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT title, points, submissionid FROM submission ORDER BY points DESC"; 

$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$count = 1;

$found = false;

$continue = true;

$records = array();

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($row !== false && $continue === true)
{ 
    if($found == false && $row['title'] == $submission)
    {
        $found = true;
    }
    elseif($found == true && $count < 6) 
    {
        $count++;
    }
    elseif($found == true && $count >= 6)
    {
        $continue = false;
    }

    $records[] = $row;
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

if($found === true)
{
    if(array_count($records) > 11)
        $records = array_splice($records, -11);
}
else
{
    $records = array();
}

echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";

for($i = 1; $i <= count($records); $i++)
{
    echo '<tr >';

    echo '<td>'.$i.'.</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename1">'.$records[$i]["title"].'</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename2"><div class="pointlink2">'.number_format($records[$i]["points"]).'</div></td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicate `"title"` values and if there are no duplicate `"points"`

```
SELECT title, points, submissionid
FROM submission 
WHERE points <=
      ( SELECT points
        FROM submission
        WHERE points >= 
              ( SELECT points
                FROM submission
                WHERE title = @row_title
              )
        ORDER BY points ASC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
      )
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to use single query and table is small and performance doesn't matters then use

```
SELECT b.title, b.points FROM (
  SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 1 as slno, temp1.* FROM (
    SELECT s1.title, s1.points, COUNT(s2.title) rank
    FROM submission s1
    JOIN submission s2 ON s1.points <= s2.points
    GROUP BY s1.title, s1.points
    ORDER BY rank, s1.title ASC
  ) as temp1 
  JOIN( SELECT @rank1 := 0 ) AS init
  ORDER BY slno 
) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as slno, temp1.* FROM (
    SELECT s1.title, s1.points, COUNT(s2.title) rank
    FROM submission s1
    JOIN submission s2 ON s1.points <= s2.points
    GROUP BY s1.title, s1.points
    ORDER BY rank, s1.title ASC
  ) as temp1 
  JOIN( SELECT @rank2 := 0 ) AS init
  ORDER BY slno 
) b ON a.slno BETWEEN b.slno - 5 AND b.slno + 5
WHERE a.title = <row_title>;
```

This will return the row selected by  and upto 5 above(if present) and upto 5 below(if present).

However, it is highly suggested to use temporary table to store ranks and the use it to display ranks.

More details about above query @
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#460

More details about optimized method @
http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/01/optimize-mysql-rank-data.html