# with mysql can I have a column generated with an autoincrement value

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql Row Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)

I'd like to number the result of a query. Can I do that with mysql?

Let's say I have the following query

```
SELECT id
       , application_id
       , 3rd_column_to_generate From SemesterApplication 
WHERE SemesterApplication.semester.id = 1 
ORDER BY SemesterApplication.modified
```

I need the query to return a 3rd column that will hold the number of the result. If the query return 20 results, that 3rd column will return value between 1 and 20.

This query will be used as a sub-query in another query.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not nice way to do this in mysql. The sort of universal hack is to create a variable and increment it. So:

```
SELECT   @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, 
         id,
         application_id,
         3rd_column_to_generate 
From     SemesterApplication,
         (select @rownum:=0) r
WHERE    SemesterApplication.semester.id = 1 
ORDER BY SemesterApplication.modified
```