# SQL syntax: delete several rows with values (id)

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

What's the MySQL syntax for deleting a certain number of rows, say, from id_1 to id_10, in the same table?

Also, if I wanted not to delete id_5, what syntax would I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete range of records at once - mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972435/how-to-delete-range-of-records-at-once-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete with the range and skip a value:

```
DELETE
FROM yourtable
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND id !=5
```

Comment: That did it; thanks also for the terminology (range). I couldn't find the right word to explain what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

for not delete id_5

```
delete from table where id != 'id_5'
```

for delete a list

```
delete from table where id in ('id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4', 
       'id_6', 'id_7', 'id_8', 'id_9', 'id_10');
```

for delete an ordered range

```
delete from table where id between 'id_1' and 'id_10';
```

or combined

```
delete from table where id between 'id_1' and 'id_10' and id!='id_5';
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, will be helpful.