# MySQL query not deleting rows using datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

Hi so I am trying to delete rows in mysql where the dates are equal to a start and end date. The problem is when I run this query:

```
DELETE FROM taddmapp.sensorsummaryall WHERE startDate = '2017-07-14T03:01:42-04:00' AND endDate = '2017-07-14T19:10:36-04:00';
```

i get an error saying "Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2017-07-14T03:01:42-04:00' for column 'startDate' at row 1".

The only thing is when i run this select query:

```
SELECT * FROM taddmapp.sensorsummaryall WHERE startDate = '2017-07-14T03:01:42-04:00' AND endDate = '2017-07-14T19:10:36-04:00';
```

with the same dates for start and end it returns me all the rows that have start and end date equal. Can someone explain why the SELECT works but the DELETE gives me an error? Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: What am I missing? _'If I run the query with the same dates for start and end, then it shows me the rows that have the same start and end dates.'_ Of course?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: and to show that `between` works for `delete` too: [How to Delete range of records at once - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972435/how-to-delete-range-of-records-at-once-mysql?lq=1)

Comment: @underscore_d i meant wy the delete isnt working? The select statement is working fine.

Comment: I doubt it. If you want to delete rows between those start and end dates, then an `and` clause is not the way to capture those rows.

Comment: @underscore_d each row has a startdate and enddate that they are equal to. sorry i didnt mean to say range.

Comment: Type of `startDate` in table?

Comment: Did you google the **error you get**? Your title does NOT reflect the error, so wondering what you found when you did your own research.

Comment: @NanaPartykar the type is datetime

Comment: @cale_b yes i googled it but they usually came up with php. im having trouble understanding why the dates are recognized when doing select but dont work when doing the delete?

Comment: MySQL does not properly support ISO 8601 format for dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format