# put two tables next to each other in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to take two tables and just put them next to each other in a result. When I do a join with out any 'on' clause or an on clause like this: '... join ... on 1' I get the cross product of the two tables, which is basically every combination of each entry in the two tables, this is not what I want, I just want to put them next to each other.

Comment: How would you match the row from left to the right? What would be the join clause?

Comment: How do you want them aligned?  How do we know that Row1 on the left should appear at the same row as row1 on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take this approach: rank every row in each table on some basis, then join the tables on the rank numbers.

Here are some questions about how to rank rows in MySQL:

- [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)
- [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: +1 - With a question as vague as this one, your answer seems to be right on spot