# Auto-increment MySQL column field on update using a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Suppose I have this code:

```
$ids = execute_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE field = 'value' ORDER BY order_field");
$query = "UPDATE table SET increment = CASE";
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($ids); $i++) {
  $query .= " WHEN id = " . $ids[$i] . " THEN " . $i;
}
$query .= " END WHERE field = 'value'";
```

Then I execute that query.

Is there a way to combine the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` into one single query that achieves the exact same thing efficiently?

Comment: In short... No. You can either perform an operation on a record _or_ do a select. You could wrap the logic inside a stored proc which would perform the update then do a select (or vice-versa). You'd only need to make one call to the database but it would still be 2 distinct operations against the table.

Comment: Is the goal to have a field numbered sequentially starting at zero?

Comment: @SomeSillyName ... pretty much (also only the fields that matches the WHERE statement and have it ordered similarly to that ORDER statement)

Comment: You could create a function, to run two without cluttering your code, but as far as I know, you can not perform two different queries in the  same line..

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607459/return-mysql-original-row-number. But, instead of updating, could you just create/display the numbering on the PHP side while looping through the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update a table while sub-selecting the same table is not possible: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html *"Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."*

I didn't run this here, but from what I understood this is what you want:

```
SET @ordering = 0;

UPDATE
  table SET increment = (@ordering := @ordering + 1)
WHERE
  field = 'value'
ORDER BY
  order_field;
```

You can execute the `SET`and `UPDATE`in separated queries, as long as you do not reconnect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
update table
    set increment = (select cnt
                     from (select count(*) as cnt
                           from table t
                           where field = 'value' and t.id <= table.id
                          ) a
                    )
    where field = 'value';
```

Comment: How does this select the table row?

Comment: @Basic . . . The subquery calculates a sequential value for the ids, which seems to be what the original code is doing (although this starts at 1 and the original code starts at 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @ordering = 100000;

UPDATE candidate 
    SET regno = (@ordering := @ordering + 1)
    WHERE 
        year = 2014 AND 
        confirm = 1 AND
        e_stat = 1 
    ORDER BY centre_code, `name`;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code may achieve the desired result, to be considered a good, helpful answer, it's best to include some context as to why/how this address the OP's issue.  An explanation will help future visitors learn how to resolve/avoid similar coding issues, and keeps the quality of SO high. Thorough answers are more likely to be upvoted, and less likely to be closed. Please `edit` to provide context, references, or your reasoning behind this code snippet. Thanks! Additional posting guidelines can be found in the SO [help](https://StackOverflow.com/help) section.