# PHP MySQL ranking system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working with the [Riot Games API](https://developer.riotgames.com) lately and got to the point where I need help or examples on how to achieve this. I have a database in mysql with the name "summoners" each summoner in the table looks like this:

[image]

There are 6 tiers (bad to good): BRONZE < SILVER < GOLD < PLATINUM < DIAMOND < CHALLENGER
There are 5 divisions: I < II < III < IV < V

What I am trying to achieve is ranking them together (tier, division and leaguepoints) and output the rank number like this:

123311: RANK#1

234453422: RANK#2

123123: RANK#3

234234234: RANK#4

Not sure on how to do this, selecting a lot of data in the database will be hard on the server?

Comment: I would make a table with tier weights, then join by it and order by weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
  FIND_IN_SET(tier,'CHALLENGER,DIAMOND,...'),
  FIND_IN_SET(division,'V,IV,III,II,I'),
  leaguepoints DESC;
```

However, it that's not performant enough for you, you could start [using `ENUM`'s and sort on those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603907/order-by-enum-field-in-mysql) ([mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-sorting))

If you need ranking directly in the query output (you might as well run a counter in application code though), [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607459/return-mysql-original-row-number)

Comment: Thanks, how would I retrieve only 1 of the results? my way of doing it would be just loop on what you have given above and getting the result index, but this wouldn't be a good idea if the table had over a 10,000 columns. Thanks again though!

Comment: s/columns/rows/ I presume. Well: frankly, I wouldn't calculate it on the fly in big sets, I would add a rank column, and I'd either make a cronjob run ever X time, or, if you fully control when the table gets updated and it's reasonably apart, run the ranking on update. You can combine the row-number answer with the sorting answer, and run an `UPDATE table SET rank=@row := @row + 1 ORDER BY ....`

Comment: I tried to update the way you showed me above but the rank field sets to 0 on all columns, my code is:      `UPDATE stats SET rank = @row := @row + 1 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(tier,"CHALLENGER,DIAMOND,PLATINUM,GOLD,SILVER,BRONZE"), FIND_IN_SET(division,"V,IV,III,II,I"), leaguePoints DESC` should also point out that I did test it without the @row := @row + 1 and put 25 there and it worked fine.

Comment: never mind got it to work by setting the variable row to 0 `SET @row = 0`. Thanks for your help I will accept this answer!