# How to apply pagination to the result of SHOW TABLES query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I would like to apply pagination to the results of `SHOW TABLES FROM DATABASE_NAME`.

Tried using the `LIMIT` keyword but an error is thrown.

By pagination I mean that the result(tables) returned by the query is to be displayed on multiple pages.

Comment: You can do it in your code, for the first page show from the first result to the number of results you want to show.  For the second one, show from result #`( number of results per page * 1 )`, until `( number of results per page * 1 ) + results per page`, and so on, just replace the `1` with the number of the current page in a zero based count (first page is 0, the second 1, etc).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use the different query instead (an achieve the names of the tables) like:

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_db_name' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: One more thing ..

Could you please modify the query to return one more column of "table no." ??

Comment: SET @rank= 0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_db_name' LIMIT 10

Comment: is this is what u want? row number

Comment: yup i want the row no. :D

but the above query is returning rank as null for each table :(

Comment: you need to run 2 queries, run the set rank before

Comment: not working .. still showing null rank .. 
executed both the queries one by one .. 
executing the queries on information_schema

Comment: use it like this with join : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number

Comment: You are a star! Thank you

Answer (score 32):

`mysql> pager less;`

`mysql> show tables;`

Comment: That is awesome

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Note that `less` must work on your system's command line already. For people that don't have `less` installed on their system, `more` might work as well. Might even work on Windows, but `less` isn't installed by default in some linux distro, especially when troubleshooting in a docker container (or any type of container).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

1)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "a%" 
LIMIT 0,20;
```

2)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'  
LIMIT 0,50;
```