# How to limit SHOW TABLES query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, information-schema

I have the following query:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '$prefix%'
```

It works exactly how I want it to, though I need pagination of the results. I tried:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '$prefix%' ORDER BY Comment ASC LIMIT 0, 6
```

I need it to return all the tables with a certain prefix and order them by their comment. I want to have pagination via the LIMIT with 6 results per page.

I'm clearly doing something very wrong. How can this be accomplished?

EDIT: I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782948/how-to-apply-pagination-to-the-result-of-show-tables-query-in-php). It didn't work for me.

Comment: Try            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782948/how-to-apply-pagination-to-the-result-of-show-tables-query-in-php/16807952#16807952

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The above cannot be done via MySQL Syntax directly. MySQL does not support the `LIMIT` clause on certain `SHOW` statements. This is one of them. [MySQL Reference Doc.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)

The below will work if your MySQL user has access to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_TO SEARCH_HERE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "table_here%"  LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: But how do I then filter if by prefix. The LIKE clause isn't working.

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE  'table%' LIMIT 0,5` works

Comment: Thanks you. But that's returning results from databases that start with that prefix. Not tables that do.

Comment: I apologize. Try this: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_HERE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "table_here%"  LIMIT 0,5;`

Answer (score 3):

Just select via a standard query instead of using SHOW TABLES.  For example

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

Then you can use things like ASC and LIMIT, etc...