# Return mysql tables having schema and token id

Tags: php, mysql

When I am trying to get all the tables from the database I got the table names with another data that I don't need; I don't know why?

[image]

Comment: what about [`show tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)?

Comment: i need to exclude some tables that's why i  need to use select

Comment: eventhough u need to execute some tables, u will still need list first and pass the table name to the code. @BagusTesa answer should work.

Comment: do you mean in the show query i can put where clause ? or after showing the table passing to other filtering rule ?

Comment: actually my answer only for showing tables, it can't filter or limit queries. it is right to use `information_schema` to query as explained [in this question-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635769/how-to-limit-show-tables-query). however, looking at your query result it certainly require post processing on the result - using regex, perhaps? anyway, just to be sure, try to run your query from mysql command line application instead of `phpmyadmin`.