# How to display mysql query result one screen at a time

Tags: mysql

I'd like to display result of my queries page by page, for example I have a Mysql db with a lot of tables and I need to see the result of `show tables;` as one screen at a time, similar to [more command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)). I know I can do a  `mysql mydb -u username -p -e 'show tables;' | more` but I need it inside inside db shell (MySQL Command-Line Tool).

So simple but I couldn't find it

Comment: See this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782948/how-to-apply-pagination-to-the-result-of-show-tables-query-in-php

Comment: You can use the LIMIT keyword to paginate the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Javier said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22142785/3990158) is the answer:

```
mysql> pager less;

mysql> show tables;
```

Comment: You can leave your custom pager, and come back to default pager: mysql> pager;

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIMIT in mysql query

**SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "a%" 
LIMIT 0,20;**

Comment: LIMIT works fine but I didn't want to modify queries whenever their results go more than a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

I would Like to add here, to exit the pager screens you simply press q to return to the terminal

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29882047)