# How to provide row no. in depending on No. of products in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, numbers, row

I have created two tables as order & product.
In order table, order details are stored & in product table according to order, product details are stored. Now I want to give row no./line no. for that product table.
Say for order no. 100 there are 3 prodcuts-:

```
1  Nokia     8000     20
2  Samsung   5000     50
3  Sony      7000     30
```

So how to give row no/line no. for product in Mysql? Is there any function for the same?
And also that no. must start from 1 for each order.
Say after order no. 100, for order no. 101, it would be again start from 1,2...like this.
I have maintained proper PK & FK...like PK of order is FK for product table..

My Schema is like this-:
First I am inserting data in Order table using insert query so that will generate id i.e. mysql_insert_id() & I am using that for reference in Product table.
Now my code is like this-:

```
    global $id;
      $id = mysql_insert_id();
      $query2 = "SELECT a.name, a.sku, a.qty_ordered, a.price, a.row_total, a.base_subtotal, 
b.base_shipping_amount, b.base_grand_total,".$id."
FROM  sales_flat_order b
JOIN sales_flat_order_item a
ON a.order_id = b.entity_id
WHERE b.increment_id = ". $order_id ;

$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $result_str_product .= "('". $row["name"] . "',". "'" . $row["sku"] . "'," . "'" . $row["qty_ordered"] . "',". "'" . $row["price"] . "'," . "'" . $row["row_total"] . "'," . "'" . $row["base_subtotal"]. "'," . "'" . $row["base_shipping_amount"] . "'," . "'" . $row["base_grand_total"] ."',". $id."),";
} 

$query3 = "INSERT into product(name, sku, qty_ordered, price, row_total, base_subtotal, base_shipping_amount,base_grand_total,prod_f) VALUES ".$result_str_product;

$final_result = substr_replace($query3,";",-1);
$result_query_product = mysql_query($final_result);
```

Now my requirement is that I want to generate line no./row no. for these products like I explain above(Plz chek my above example that Nokia,Samsung.
So How I can give row no./line no. for these item? Any in-built function for the same that I can use in while loop or any other approach?

Comment: Check this one out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number