# Getting data sample to plot

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table on mysql with lots and lots of data (like >10000), and it seems pretty slow to load all the data to Java and then plot a graphic. I would like to get just a few points to plot a graphic, but I have no idea how. Like, getting data every 10 or 100 rows. Any idea?

Comment: You could easily plot all of it if you queried for it in chunks.  Or you you query for a LIMIT of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an auto increment field you can simply select every 10 or 100 rows using remainder (mod):

```
SELECT actor_id, last_name FROM actor WHERE MOD(actor_id, 10) = 0;
```

You can also give each row a row number and limit your result on that:

```
SELECT actor_id, last_name, row_number FROM
(SELECT actor_id, last_name, @currentRow := @currentRow + 1 AS row_number FROM
actor JOIN (SELECT @currentRow := 0) Row) Data
WHERE MOD(row_number, 10) = 0;
```

The cool row number technique is by Daniel Vassallo. [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)

Good luck :)

Comment: Both answers helped me a lot, I'll accept yours because the rownum is a nice workaround that I didn't know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can divide your whole interval min(x) - max(x) to N intervals and get only one average point per interval. For instance (10 intervals here) something like this:

```
select round((x-@minx)/@step),avg(y) from PLOT_DATA,
(select @minx:=min(x),
        @maxx:=max(x),
        @intervals:=10, /*separated intervals count*/
        @step:=(@maxx-@minx)/@intervals
  from PLOT_DATA) t

group by round((x-@minx)/@step)
order by round((x-@minx)/@step)
```