# Numbering rows on condition

Tags: mysql

I need at select rows from table, make numbering rows so: first 3 rows numbering as:

```
1  
2  
3
```

and after ( from the fourth row ), start numbering again and this second numbering continue to the end of all records, that is result must be like this:

```
1  
2  
3  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
....  
....  
777
```

I write this query, but this returns usual numbering, from 1 to last record.

Please, someone tell me, where have I logical wrong in my query? In my opinion, this will returns numbring, as I write above

```
mysql-> SET @n = 0
mysql-> SET @start_again = 'true'


SELECT 

        CASE 
            WHEN  @n = 3 AND @start_again = 'true' THEN  @n := 1
            ELSE @n := @n + 1
        END,

        CASE 
            WHEN  @n = 3 AND @start_again = 'true' THEN  @start_again := 'false'
        END

FROM mytable
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: I not obtain error, this query works, but incorrect, this returns usuall numbering from 1 to last record. But I need, from the fourth row, start numbering again

Comment: What is the difference here to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459340/custom-row-numbering – which has an answer marked as correct???

Comment: @feeela, in old question I need this numbering: **1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3**
.In this question I ask, how make this numbering: **1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating your task.

```
SET @n = 0
SELECT if((@n := @n + 1) > 3, @n - 3, @n) AS n ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you can , tell me, what is incorrect in my query? why it works incorrect ?

Comment: Because when `@n` is 2, your first `CASE` sees that it is NOT 3 and increments it to 3, _then_ your second `CASE` sees that it is 3 and resets `@start_again` to false. On the next iteration, `@n` is 3, but `@start_again` is already false; the first `CASE` never sees a situation where `@n` is 3 and `@start_again` is true simultaneously.