# Django JOIN query without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there a way in Django to write a query using the ORM, not raw SQL that allows you to JOIN on another table without there being a foreign key? Looking through the documentation it appears in order for the One to One relationship to work there must be a foreign key present?

In the models below I want to run a query with a JOIN on UserActivity.request_url to UserActivityLink.url.

```
class UserActivity(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_activity_ip = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    last_activity_browser = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    last_activity_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    request_url = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    users_id = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_activity'

class UserActivityLink(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    url_description = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_activity_link'
```

The link table has a more descriptive translation of given URLs in the system, this is needed for some reporting the system will generate.

I've tried creating the foreign key from UserActivity.request_url to UserActivityLink.url but it fails with the following error: ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I'm wondering what would happen if you defined your UserActivity.request_url field as a ForeignKey with `to_field='url'`.

Comment: I tried that same thing via Workbench but if barfed an error. I tried to create a foreign key relationship from UserActivity.request_url TO UserActivityLink.url but got the following error, not sure why or what it really means: ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there isn't an effective way unfortunately.

The `.raw()` is there for this exact thing. Even if it could it probably would be a lot slower than raw SQL.

There is a blogpost [here](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/) detailing how to do it with `query.join()` but as they themselves point out. It's not best practice.

Answer (score 11):

Just reposting some related answer, so everyone could see it.
Taken from here: [Most efficient way to use the django ORM when comparing elements from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681992/most-efficient-way-to-use-the-django-orm-when-comparing-elements-from-two-lists)

> #### First problem: joining unrelated models
>
> I'm assuming that your `Model1` and `Model2` are not related,
>   otherwise you'd be able to use [Django's related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/)
>   interface. Here are two approaches you could take:
>
> 1. Use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) and a SQL subquery:
>
>    ```
>    Model1.objects.extra(where = ['field in (SELECT field from myapp_model2 WHERE ...)'])
>    ```
>
>    Subqueries are not handled very efficiently in some databases
>      (notably MySQL) so this is probably not as good as #2 below.
> 2. Use a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/):
>
>    ```
>    Model1.objects.raw('''SELECT * from myapp_model1
>                       INNER JOIN myapp_model2
>                       ON myapp_model1.field = myapp_model2.field
>                       AND ...''')
>    ```
>
> #### Second problem: enumerating the result
>
> Two approaches:
>
> 1. You can enumerate a query set in Python using the built-in [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:
>
>    ```
>    enumerate(Model1.objects.all())
>    ```
> 2. You can use the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127004/68063) to do the enumeration in MySQL. Something like this:
>
>    ```
>    Model1.objects.raw('''SELECT *, @row := @row + 1 AS row
>                       FROM myapp_model1
>                       JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) rowtable
>                       INNER JOIN myapp_model2
>                       ON myapp_model1.field = myapp_model2.field
>                       AND ...''')
>    ```

Answer (score 10):

The Django `ForeignKey` is different from SQL ForeignKey. Django ForeignKey just represent a relation, it can specify whether to use database constraints.

Try this:

```py
request_url = models.ForeignKey(UserActivityLink, to_field='url_description', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_constraint=False)
```

Note that the `db_constraint=False` is **required**, without it Django will build a SQL like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `user_activity` ADD CONSTRAINT `xxx` FOREIGN KEY (`request_url`) REFERENCES `user_activity_link` (`url_description`);"
```

I met the same problem, after a lot of research, I found the above method.

Hope it helps.