# How to create a django queryset object for inner join?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have two tables.

```
class DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate(models.Model):
    nsn = models.TextField()
    nsn2 = models.TextField()
    cage = models.TextField()
    part_number = models.TextField()
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    supplier = models.TextField(db_column='Supplier', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cost = models.CharField(db_column='Cost', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    list_price = models.CharField(db_column='List_Price', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gsa_price = models.CharField(db_column='GSA_Price', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hash = models.TextField()
    nomenclature = models.TextField()
    technical_documents = models.TextField()
    solicitation = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    purchase_request = models.TextField()
    issued = models.DateField()
    return_by = models.DateField()
    file = models.TextField()
    vendor_part_number = models.TextField()
    manufacturer_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dibbs_spider_dibbs_matched_product_fields_duplicate'


class DibbsSpiderSolicitation(models.Model):
    line_items = models.IntegerField()
    nsn = models.TextField()
    nomenclature = models.TextField()
    technical_documents = models.TextField()
    purchase_request = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dibbs_spider_solicitation'
```

What will be the equivalent django query for the inner join of two tables on the column `nsn`?
My views function will be like

```
def inner(request,nsn):
    u_m =  DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.objects.filter(nsn2__icontains=id)
    c_m = DibbsSpiderSolicitation.objects.filter(nsn__icontains=id)
    obj = .......................
    context = {'obj':obj}
    return render(request,,"a.html",context)
```

the queryset should return the combination of two tables according to the common nsn.

the obj should return the combination of `u_m` and `c_m`. If `u_m` contains only one rows and `c_m` contains many rows then the obj must replicate the values of u_m.

Answer (score 2):

You can try some of the options:

1. Adding foreign key constraint and use select_related as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django)
2. Raw query as mentioned in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669422/django-join-query-without-foreign-key) and another post with [custom joins](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/)

3. Using IN query as per the following logic:

```
DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.objects.filter(
        nsn2__in=DibbsSpiderSolicitation.objects.filter(nsn__icontains='text_to_search').values('origin'))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, great model names. Let's alias them:
DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate is *Apples*; DibbsSpiderSolicitation is *Oranges*

```
inner_qs = Apples.objects.all().extra(
    tables=("yourapp_oranges",),
    where=("yourapp_apples.nsn=yourapp_oranges.nsn",),
)
```

The documentation mentions that this api will be deprecated:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Answer (score -1):

### Option #1 - Introduce a ForeignKey (Recommended):

Under the class `DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate` add:

```py
fkey = models.ForeignKey('DibbsSpiderSolicitation')
```

then you can easily access their join:

```py
obj = DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.Objects.filter(fkey__nsn).select_related()
```

Now it is your choice what you wish to do with `nsn2`

### Option #2 - without a ForeigKey:

#### Raw SQL:

```py
obj = DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.objects.extra(where = ['''SELECT *
FROM DibbsSpiderSolicitation
INNER JOIN DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate
ON DibbsSpiderSolicitation.nsn = DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.nsn2;'''])
# or
obj = DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.objects.raw('''SELECT *
FROM DibbsSpiderSolicitation
INNER JOIN DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate
ON DibbsSpiderSolicitation.nsn = DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.nsn2;''')
```

#### Using filter:

```py
obj = DibbsSpiderSolicitation.objects.filter(nsn__in=DibbsSpiderDibbsMatchedProductFieldsDuplicate.objects.nsn2)
```

Sorry, I was not able to test any.