# How to ensure that ids remain continuous after a record is deleted?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with multiple tables. One table is called "users". An example of the data is

```
0 John Black
1 Joe Bloggs
2 Jane Doe
```

If I perform a delete on row `where id = 1` the data becomes:

```
0 John Black
2 Jane Doe
```

What SQL would I write to alter the further records to decrement the ID, so that the data becomes:

```
0 John Black
1 Jane Doe
```

**Note:** There are other tables with related data so e.g employee details may have address and phone number linked via the ID column, but I assume this would also change, as `ON UPDATE` is set to "cascade"

Comment: probably not a good idea

Comment: Why do you need to have gapless ids?

Comment: you would be reshuffling your whole database. if you dont have cascading set everywhere you might orphan records not to mention the unnecessary thing of doing it anywat

Comment: plus Jane Doe is user or customer #2. probably printed on documents

Comment: You'll completely trash your references to User ID 1 if you do this. Suddenly Jane Doe will be linked in place of Joe Bloggs. If you miss one of these by accident, suddenly you've exposed some of Joe's data to Jane. Generally IDs, once assigned, should *never* be changed unless you have an exceptionally good reason. OCD does not qualify.

Comment: I don't see any positive reason in doing that, are you afraid of consume every id? Don't worry, DBs manage that for you.

Comment: funny ocd was the first thing i thought of

Comment: Also, you will not run out of ids, if you do then just make the type larger or make a key out of two columns.

Comment: heres a news for you: you are not even quaranteed ID-s to be sequential after multiple INSERTs. (mysql >= 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we never change an ID in a database for integrity reasons and there's no problem having gaps in a database. It's normal!

You are not supposed to find a record based on a row number.  If you are having problems because of gaps, you need to rethink your design in your application.

but if it's for a display reason, I recommend using the [Row_Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wanted to you could:

1. write a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) that on deleting a record
2. updates all the ids that are greater than the one being deleted by -1
3. then updates all tables that refer to this table.

Depending on the database you are using you maybe need to drop the foreign key constraints at the beginning of the transaction and re-enable them at the end.

---

**But** you are probably solving the wrong problem here. This seems like a bad idea resulting from analness rather than any real need.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT change your identities. This would be like the bank changing your account numbers every time someone left the bank. There is far too much room at stake here for things to go wrong.

An alternative to what you are trying to do would be to have a sort_order column and have that fix itself. Every time there is deletions have a trigger update the column using the mysql version of the MS SQL function RANK function based on UserID ASC.

This would give you the same desirable output but without breaking any table links.

Regards,

Marcus