# SQL Find Position in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mySql which has the users ID and scores.

What I would like to do is organise the table by scores (simple) but then find where a certain user ID sits in the table.

So far I would have:

```
SELECT * FROM table_score
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

How would I find where `userID = '1234'` is  (i.e entry 10 of 12)

Comment: Checkout the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following query will give you a new column `UserRank`, which specify the user rank:

```
SELECT 
  UserID, 
  Score, 
  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) UserRank 
FROM table_score, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc9b5/5)

This will give you something like:

```
| USERID | SCORE | USERRANK |
-----------------------------
|      4 |   100 |        1 |
|     10 |    70 |        2 |
|      2 |    55 |        3 |
|   1234 |    50 |        4 |
|      1 |    36 |        5 |
|     20 |    33 |        6 |
|      8 |    25 |        7 |
```

Then you can put this query inside a subquery and filter with a `userId` to get that user rank. Something like:

```
SELECT
  t.UserRank
FROM
(
   SELECT *, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) UserRank 
   FROM table_score, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
   ORDER BY Score DESC
) t
WHERE userID = '1234';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc9b5/1)

Comment: if have records with duplicate USERID how i can edit this query? thank!

Answer (score 2):

For a given user id, you can do this with a simple query:

```
select sum(case when ts.score >= thescore.score then 1 else 0 end) as NumAbove,
       count(*) as Total
from table_score ts cross join
     (select ts.score from table_score ts where userId = '1234') thescore
```

If you have indexes on score and userid, this will be quite efficient.