# How to get MySQL offset as a column with alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, offset

How to get MySQL offset as a column with alias?

What I need is a way to get the current offset as a column in my sql query.

```
SELECT *, <THE_CURRENT_QUERY_OFFSET> AS current_query_offset
  FROM test_table
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 25
```

So, I should have a column named current_query_offset which is 25 in each row.

Note: I don't need the current row position the way it is given in [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number) .

Comment: When you say `LIMIT/OFFSET` i assume, you must put order in you data. And what is meaning of `LIMIT 0`?

Comment: It was a typo. I have fixed it. Thanks for prompting.

Comment: Its better you keep the offset in a variable and use it in your query

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve (that is: selecting a named column containing a constant value along with any other columns), this will work:

```
SELECT *, 25 AS current_query_offset
FROM test_table
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 25;
```

Since you're supplying the value `25` to your sql code once already, I don't see why you shouldn't do it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT *, 25 AS current_query_offset
FROM test_table
LIMIT 0 OFFSET current_query_offset
```

Comment: did you really test this? I think not because you cannot do this.