# Introducing a column of numbers that count from 1-381

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 381 records with the columns **id,name,dept_id**.

How would I introduce a column called **row_id** with numbers that count from 1-381 (to uniquely identify each row and they need to auto-increment from this point afterwards).

I would need to write this in MySQL. The only other way I can think of is manually entering this but it would take too long.

Comment: How is `row_id` going to be different than the existing `id`? In general, you are asking about a possible solution to a problem, while you should be asking directly about the problem you want to solve.

Comment: why do you need that extra column?

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new column `alter table table_name add column row_id int()` then execute this command `SELECT @i:=0;UPDATE table_name SET row_id = @i:=@i+1`then make it primary key and set it as auto increment