# determine which row number a result is - mysql

Tags: mysql

How could I find which number result a specific row is in a table?

For example, a table with names and ratings (ratings do not stay constant),

```
| name  |  rating  |
+-------+----------|
|  me   +     14   |
+-------+----------|
|  you  +    15    |
+-------+----------|
```

The query can only select one row at a time, so I'd like to incorporate this into it.

`select name,rating,?????? from table where name = 'you' ORDER BY rating`

how can i return `'you','15','2'`?

i get the feeling i'm missing something very simple here...

Comment: Why not include an AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table, or otherwise include an incrementing integer you can select?

Comment: ultimately the order will change, so it won't be based on any static column value... ratings will fluctuate for example

Comment: Ahh, so you want the row's index in the resultset *after ordering by rating*. You didn't mention the ordering in your question.

Comment: Well, there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do a "ranking" query, as described in this article? http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

Answer (score 0):

This would be ok:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, t.name, t.rating
FROM table t,(SELECT @i:=0) foo
```