# Select a non existing column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible say for example i want to select a column which does not exist in an mysql table, i just want this column to have incremental values starting from "somevalue (100 maybe)". I want something like this:

```
my dummy column | other existing columns | blah
100
101
102
```

is this possible in mysql?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number should help you

Answer (score 13):

Yes sure, You can named column with `as` keyword. For example:

```
SELECT 1 as 'hello'
```

And You can simply add RowNumber column like below example:

```
SELECT t.*, 
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 as RowNumber
FROM your_table t, 
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

> For start from `149`, You just need to replace `(SELECT @rownum := 0)` with `(SELECT @rownum := 149)`

> For a dummy column with the certain type, Use `Cast` or `Convert` functions like this: `CAST(@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS CHAR) AS RowNumber`. You can find more about this here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

More Examples related to the comments:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(col1) AS col2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col2
HAVING col2 = 2;
```

@nodsdorf example in the comments:

```
SELECT
    (1+1) AS dummy,
    other_column
FROM table
```

Comment: another example:
SELECT COUNT(col1) AS col2 FROM t GROUP BY col2 HAVING col2 = 2;

Comment: i want it to increment along with the other existing columns in the table and i want it to start at 149.

Comment: how about if i want to select just a dummy column but i want this column to have a certain format like say for example a "longtext" type

Comment: you can use CAST/CONVERT functions:
replace this line of example: CAST(@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS CHAR) AS RowNumber and check this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: use math function as a dummy column.. SELECT (1+1) AS dummy, other_column FROM table