# How to Select 1 Row From Each 10 Rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am recording a real time change of a given signal into my database table.

Then I draw line graph to visualize the change of the signal level.

I want to get (10n+1)<sup>th</sup> rows in the table to make a rough graph. 10 is also arbitrary. User may change it to another value.

Does someone know how to make this ***just using a MySQL Query***

If no, I will go with PHP after selecting all the data.

Here my table structure is:

```
|id        |signal1   |signal2   | signal 3   |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|1         |0.41452   | 1.32135  | 0.31231    |
...
```

Comment: What does your table structure look like?

Comment: You could use `group by` on the time of the entry (manipulated to a grouping -ie format y-m-d H:i ) OR more accurately use row number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number

Comment: Do you need record number 1,10,20,30,40 and 50 like. If there is only 50 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an auto_incrememt id column, you can select rows that are divisible by n

```
SELECT * FROM tableName1 WHERE MOD(id,10)=0; 
// id divided by 10 with a remainder equal to 0 (exact)
```

or without sequential column id's

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rowNum, colName1 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, tableName1
    ) ranked 
WHERE rowNum % 10 = 1
```

Comment: Note that using `mod(id, 10)` will give correct results only if there are no gaps in the numbering (no rows have been deleted).

Answer (score 0):

If your table has auto increment id (intID), then you should try this code.There are only 26 records in my table.

```
select * from tablename where intId 
        in (select case  (intId%10=0) when 1 then intId else 0 end as x from tablename )
```

Output :-

```
10  sdf KK201300010 123456  Regular
20  sdf KK201300020 123456  Regular
```

It will displaying each record in every 10 record.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am looking to implement this code that you recommended into a site but I have a few questions. What does the code mean exactly? How does it translate? "end as x" what is it doing here? do you have a recommendation as to how to best use it with php?

Comment: To better clarify, I am trying to select every hundred rows. I am trying to create a next button that will pull every 100 rows with every click of the next button or arrow. Like a pagination but without the number of the pages.