# get last record in file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (rather ugly designed, but anyway), which consists only of strings. The worst is that there is a script which adds records time at time. Records will never be deleted.

I believe, that MySQL store records in a random access file, and I can get last or any other record using C language or something, since I know the max length of the record and I can find EOF.

When I do something like "`SELECT * FROM table`" in MySQL I get all the records in the right order - cause MySQL reads this file from the beginning to the end. I need only the last one(s).

Is there a way to get the LAST record (or records) using MySQL query only, without `ORDER BY`?

---

Well, I suppose I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number), so my current query is

```
SELECT 
   @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, 
   t.* 
FROM 
   table t,
   (SELECT @i:=0) i 
ORDER BY 
     iterator DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If there's a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: Is there an AUTO INCREMENT column in the schema?

Comment: why no order by? order by is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Use ORDER BY, and be sure to put an index on that column.

Comment: Whay are you so keen to avoid using `ORDER BY`?

Comment: There is no AUTO INCREMENT column - actually, there are only two columns - two strings. If I use ORDER BY I will get orders sorted in alphabetic way, I'm afraid.

Comment: `ORDER BY` will sort according to what you tell it. If you say to `ORDER BY string`, where _string_ is a string column containing a number then it will sort alphabetically. However, in that case `ORDER BY CONV(string, 10, 10)` then it will sort numerically.

Comment: I need to sort them by the order they were added, though there is no information about that in the  table

Answer (score 2):

The order is not guaranteed unless you use an `ORDER BY`. It just happens that the records you're getting back are sorted the way need them.

Comment: Yes, that's not guaranteed, but since it's a random access file and I never delete records - the newest one will always be at the end - therefore I can get them using other methods. But I wonder if there is a way to use MySQL features?

Comment: It's pure chance that the order returned is by the physical order. You need to have a column that can be sorted and then you can try something as suggested by Bere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the importance of keys (primary key for example). 
You can make some modification in your table by adding a `primary key column` with `auto_increment` default value. 
Then you can query

`select * from your_table where id =(select max(id) from your_table);`

and get the last inserted row.

Comment: Yes, I know the table is ugly designed, but can I do it without changing it?

Comment: @shomel once you know your table is ugly and start to feel its 'pinch' that is the right time to modify it :)