# First three Groups with Highest Marks should have specific points 5,3, 1

Tags: mysql

my table

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| NAME | GROUP1 | SECTION | MARKS | POINTS |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| S1   | G1     | class1  |    55 | (null) |
| S16  | G1     | class1  |    55 | (null) |
| S17  | G1     | class1  |    55 | (null) |

| S2   | (null) | class2  |    33 | (null) |

| S25  | G10    | class1  |    55 | (null) |
| S26  | G10    | class1  |    55 | (null) |

| S4   | G88    | class2  |    65 | (null) |
| S5   | G88    | class2  |    65 | (null) |
| S32  | (null) | class1  |    65 | (null) |

| S7   | G5     | class1  |    32 | (null) |
| S18  | G5     | class1  |    32 | (null) |

| S10  | (null) | class2  |    78 | (null) |

| S8   | G8     | class1  |    22 | (null) |
| S20  | G8     | class1  |    22 | (null) |

| S22  | G9     | class1  |    20 | (null) |
| S23  | G9     | class1  |    20 | (null) |

| S13  | G55    | class2  |    33 | (null) |
| S36  | G55    | class2  |    33 | (null) |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
```

SQL FIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b54/1/0

I have raised this question before, according to the comments I tried to improve the question more clear.

I am trying to give specific points to first 3 groups with highest marks in each Section. I would like to add 5 points to each student who got highest Mark in a Section, 3 points for 2nd highest Marks and 1 points for 3rd highest group. Duplicate Marks may occur for group.

eg: in class1  - Group 'G1' and 'G10' got '55' and they got highest mark in 'class1'. So i would like to give '5' points to all students in Group 'G1' and' G10'.

Group G5 got second highest marks, so all student in that group should give 3 points. Same way G8 - 1 point.

plz note : any student who doesnt have Group ID that student is participating single item, do not consider that records.

I am using following code, this code works fine for individual students, dont know how to give points to the Group members.

```
select t1.Name, t1.Section, t1.Marks from myTable t1 join 
(select Section, substring_index(group_concat (distinct Marks order by Marks desc),    
',', 3) as Marks3  from myTable where Section = 'class1' group by Section ) tsum  
on t1.Section = tsum.Section and find_in_set(t1.Marks, tsum.Marks3) > 0 
ORDER BY Section, Marks DESC, ID Desc
```

My final output looks for a Section. Plz give only one Section (class1)

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| NAME | GROUP1 | SECTION | MARKS | POINTS |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| S1   | G1     | class1  |    55 |    5   |
| S16  | G1     | class1  |    55 |    5   |
| S17  | G1     | class1  |    55 |    5   |

| S2   | (null) | class2  |    33 | (null) |

| S25  | G10    | class1  |    55 |    5   |
| S26  | G10    | class1  |    55 |    5   |

| S4   | G88    | class2  |    65 | (null) |
| S5   | G88    | class2  |    65 | (null) |

| S32  | (null) | class1  |    65 | (null) |

| S7   | G5     | class1  |    32 |    3   |
| S18  | G5     | class1  |    32 |    3   |

| S10  | (null) | class2  |    78 | (null) |

| S8   | G8     | class1  |    22 |    1   |
| S20  | G8     | class1  |    22 |    1   |

| S22  | G9     | class1  |    20 | (null) |
| S23  | G9     | class1  |    20 | (null) |

| S13  | G55    | class2  |    33 | (null) |
| S36  | G55    | class2  |    33 | (null) |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Kindly Help me..

Comment: You just asked the same the question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404726/first-three-groups-with-highest-marks-should-have-specific-points

Comment: You should be knowing that you can edit questions if needed

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404726/first-three-groups-with-highest-marks-should-have-specific-points#18405671) answer is given by *Itay*

```
SELECT t1.`id`,  t1.`name`,  t1.`group1`,
       t1.`section`, t1.`MARKS`, `t_group_points`.`points`

FROM   `students` t1

LEFT JOIN (
    (
        SELECT `t4`.`group1`, `t_points`.`points`
        FROM   (SELECT   `t3`.`group1`, AVG(`t3`.`marks`) AS `avg`
                FROM     `students` `t3`
                WHERE    (`t3`.`section` = 'class1') AND
                         (`t3`.`group1` IS NOT NULL)
                GROUP BY `t3`.`group1`) `t4`

        INNER JOIN (
              (SELECT `top`.`avg`,
                      CASE @curRow := @curRow + 1  
                           WHEN '1' THEN 5
                           WHEN '2' THEN 3
                           WHEN '3' THEN 1
                           ELSE NULL END 'points'

              FROM (SELECT `t_avg`.`avg`
                    FROM   (SELECT   `t2`.`group1`, AVG(`t2`.`marks`) AS `avg`
                            FROM     `students` `t2`
                            WHERE    (`t2`.`section` = 'class1') AND
                                     (`t2`.`group1` IS NOT NULL)
                            GROUP BY `group1`) `t_avg`
                    GROUP BY `t_avg`.`avg`
                    ORDER BY `avg` DESC
                    LIMIT 0, 3) `top`, (SELECT @curRow:=0) r
              ) AS `t_points`)
         ON (`t_points`.`avg` = `t4`.`avg`)      
    ) AS `t_group_points`)
ON (`t_group_points`.`group1` = `t1`.`group1`)
```