# How to use user-defined variables in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to answer another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404726) and was suddenly faced with the following problem. Points should be assigned to the 3 highest scoring (`mrk`) groups (`grp`) of each class (`sec`). The highest scoring groups get 5 points, the second ranking ones 3 points and the groups in 3rd rank only 1 point. For all others `pts` should be set to `null`.

```
| ID | SEC | GRP | MRK |    PTS |
|----|-----|-----|-----|--------|
|  1 | cl2 |  ge |  32 | (null) |
|  2 | cl1 |  gb |  22 | (null) |
|  3 | cl1 |  gd |  22 | (null) |
|  4 | cl1 |  ge |  18 | (null) |
|  5 | cl2 |  ga |  26 | (null) |
|  6 | cl1 |  ga |  55 | (null) |
|  7 | cl2 |  gb |  66 | (null) |
|  8 | cl2 |  gc |  15 | (null) |
|  9 | cl1 |  gc |  12 | (null) |
| 10 | cl2 |  gf |   5 | (null) |
| 11 | cl2 |  ge |  66 | (null) |
```

I chose to work with user-defined variables as they provide maximum flexibility regarding the allocation scheme and soon came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT id,sec,grp,mrk,
CASE WHEN @s=sec THEN          -- whenever there is a new class ...
 CASE WHEN @m=mrk THEN @i ELSE -- issue the same points for 
                               -- identical scorers, otherwise ...
  CASE WHEN IF(@m:=mrk,@i,@i)>2 THEN @i:=@i-2  -- store mrk in @mrk and 
                               -- while @i>2 return points: 3 or 1 ...
                                ELSE @i:=null  -- no points for the rest
  END
 END
 ELSE NULLIF(@i:=5,(@s:=sec)=(@m:=mrk)) -- store sec in @s and mrk in @m
                                        -- and return points: 5
END pts
FROM tbl ORDER BY sec,mrk desc
```

Explanation of `NULLIF(@i:=5,(@s:=sec)=(@m:=mrk))`:

The expressions `@s:=sec` and `@m:=mrk` are both evaluated and then their values are compared by `=`. The result can either be `0` (false) or `1` (true) but it will definitely be unequal to `5`, the other argument of the `NULLIF` function, therefore in the end only the first argument (`5`) will be returned. I chose the construct to make the two variable assignments happen without returning anything.

OK, maybe not the most straightforward solution ;-), but I *did pay attention* to define each variable only once for each record that is being processed, since "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined" [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). The `select` indeed gives me the desired

result:

```
| ID | SEC | GRP | MRK |    PTS |
|----|-----|-----|-----|--------|
|  6 | cl1 |  ga |  55 |      5 |
|  2 | cl1 |  gb |  22 |      3 |
|  3 | cl1 |  gd |  22 |      3 |
|  4 | cl1 |  ge |  18 |      1 |
|  9 | cl1 |  gc |  12 | (null) |
|  7 | cl2 |  gb |  66 |      5 |
| 11 | cl2 |  ge |  66 |      5 |
|  1 | cl2 |  ge |  32 |      3 |
|  5 | cl2 |  ga |  26 |      1 |
|  8 | cl2 |  gc |  15 | (null) |
| 10 | cl2 |  gf |   5 | (null) |
```

Now, my question is:

**How do I write an `UPDATE` statement along the same lines that will store the above calculated results in column `pts`?**

My attempts so far have all failed:

```
UPDATE tbl SET pts=
CASE WHEN @s=sec THEN
 CASE WHEN @m=mrk THEN @i ELSE
  CASE WHEN IF(@m:=mrk,@i,@i)>2 THEN @i:=@i-2 
                                ELSE @i:=null 
  END
 END
 ELSE NULLIF(@i:=5,(@s:=sec)=(@m:=mrk)) 
END
ORDER BY sec,mrk desc
```

result:

```
| ID | SEC | GRP | MRK | PTS |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  6 | cl1 |  ga |  55 |   5 |
|  2 | cl1 |  gb |  22 |   5 |
|  3 | cl1 |  gd |  22 |   5 |
|  4 | cl1 |  ge |  18 |   5 |
|  9 | cl1 |  gc |  12 |   5 |
|  7 | cl2 |  gb |  66 |   5 |
| 11 | cl2 |  ge |  66 |   5 |
|  1 | cl2 |  ge |  32 |   5 |
|  5 | cl2 |  ga |  26 |   5 |
|  8 | cl2 |  gc |  15 |   5 |
| 10 | cl2 |  gf |   5 |   5 |
```

Why does the update statement only get a single value (5) for pts?!?

You can find all the data and SQL statements in my [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1461/6).

Comment: what your wished update result.

Comment: @echo_Me my desired UPDATE result is listed in my post under "The select indeed gives me the desired result:". FYI: I also tried inserting the `SELECT` output into a (temporary) table -> same result as shown at the bottom of my post :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to debug this case.
I've added 6 new columns to the `tbl` table: b_s, b_m, b_i and a_s, a_m, a_i 
b_* - means "before", a_* - means "after",
and I've modified the query to:

```
UPDATE tbl SET 
   b_s = @s,
   b_m = @m,
   b_i = @i, 
pts=
CASE WHEN @s=sec THEN
 CASE WHEN @m=mrk THEN @i ELSE
  CASE WHEN IF(@m:=mrk,@i,@i)>2 THEN @i:=@i-2 
                                ELSE @i:=null 
  END
 END
 ELSE NULLIF(@i:=5,(@s:=sec)=(@m:=mrk)) 
END,
a_s = @s,
a_m = @m,
a_i = @i 
ORDER BY sec,mrk desc
```

My intent was to log values of variables before and after of the expression evaluation.
It's strange - I don't know why, but it seems that when you assign values to all variables **before the execution of the update** then the update works as expected.
Compare these two demos:
1 - wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db3e4/1 
2 - fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37ff5/1

The only difference is this code fragment before the update:

```
set @i='alamakota';
set @m='alamakota';
set @s='alamakota';
```

Some kind on "magic string" :)

Comment: Interesting obervation and good idea with the before and after columns! I will play around with the fiddle too ...

Comment: Strange thing. Is it documented anywhere?!? Will there be a possibility of writing everything in a single statement (without the `SET ...` commands before)?

Comment: Well, that probably *is* the answer then: **Variables you want to use in an `UPDATE` must be *declared* (they are also bound to a char-type) using some kind of `SET` statement before.** (`SET @s:=@m:=@i:='a'` also works.) Although I have found a (simpler) example in the posts under the UPDATE section of the MySQL manual for switching columns: `UPDATE tbl SET sec=(@v:=sec), sec=grp, grp=@v;`. (This statement works *without* the previous `SET`.) However, in this example, the variable `@v` is *never tested* (has its value checked) in a `CASE` construct.

Comment: It seems a problem by not initializing user-defined variables, here's a curious example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bc95/1). The same query returns a wrong result but causes the UPDATE to work properly.

On my server I reproduced the problem, but only happens the first time after restarting MySQL, the following sometimes works as expected.

Similarly initializing variables to NULL `SET @i := @s := @m := NULL;` works as expected.