# Find position in active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a league table that i create with:

```
 QuizuserAnswer.all(:include =>:user, :select => 'user_id, SUM(answer) AS points', :group =>'user_id', :order=>'points DESC'
```

This returns an object like this:

```
 => [#<QuizuserAnswer user_id: 340>, #<QuizuserAnswer user_id: 348>]
```

Now i want to find the league table position of one specific user. Is there a clean way? or do i have to loop through al columns?

Comment: What do you mean by _position of one specific user_?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: If you are using MySQL then follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/q/3126972/1460496

Comment: I'm using mysql. With position i meant the row number, because they reflect the position of a user in the league table

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a very little i got your question i think you want something like following

```
answers = QuizuserAnswer.all(:include =>:user, :select => 'user_id, SUM(answer) AS points', :group =>'user_id', :order=>'points DESC')
user_id = 348
answers.map(&:user_id).index(user_id) #This will return 1
```

i.e It will return the position of the answer given by the user among the answer's list

Comment: @flyte321 :- Cheer's, remember one thing it will return `nil` if `user_id` is not present in `answers`

Comment: This actually solved my issue of trying to generate a "next" button in an action record collection with a scope