# How to store one or more column with mysql data in an array

Tags: php, mysql

The output I get

```
Name    Age
ABC     12
PQR     40
XYZ     10
```

code for retrieving data from MySql database using PHP.

```
  //Get records from database
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people;");

    //Add all records to an array
    $rows = array();
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     // Here i want to bind one more colomn for count as Row number to array
        count = count + 1;
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

**desired output..**

```
RowNo    Name    Age
 1       ABC     12
 2       PQR     40
 3       XYZ     10
```

I want to send count number with `mysql data as one colomn`. Can anybody guide me to on that?

Comment: don't use mysql_<> functions please

Comment: Then suggest an alternative instead of saying what not to use.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number
(you don't have to iterate through anything in PHP, you can get it from mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $count = $count + 1;
    $row['RowNo']= $count; //Just add this
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$counter = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{
   $counter++;
   $result[$i]['rowcount'] = $counter;
}
```