# MySQL - Cannot Create View with SET variable inside

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view with `SET @rank = 0;` inside but it's giving me errors. Been trying different things but it's not working. Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

```
CREATE VIEW S1_Bottom_Performer_AHT as (
SET @rank=0
SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS '#',
                ei.SM,
                ei.TM,
                es.Month_Date,
                ei.emp_id,
                ei.DNAME,
                ei.STATUS,
                ei.SHIFT,
                ei.SKILL,
                ei.HIRE_DATE,
                ifnull(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ei.HIRE_DATE, now()), '-') AS Tenure,
                ifnull(es.Call_Handled, '-') AS Call_Handled,
                ifnull(es.AHT, '-') AS AHT
FROM mtl_extended_info ei
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT es.Employee_ID,
           es.Month_Date,
           sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct) AS Call_Handled,
           round((sum(es.I_Talk_Time_Sec) + sum(es.Hold_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_Work_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) AS AHT
   FROM cdl_agent_call_voume_gen es
   WHERE es.Month_Date = '2013-09-01'
   GROUP BY es.Employee_ID,
            es.Month_Date ) es ON es.Employee_ID = ei.emp_id
WHERE es.Month_Date = '2013-09-01'
  AND ei.Visible = 1
  AND ei.SKILL != 'RSD'
GROUP BY ei.emp_id
ORDER BY es.AHT DESC LIMIT 80);
```

Error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @rank=0
SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS '#',
                ei.SM,
          ' at line 2
```

Comment: What is your mysql version? I 've tried to create a view which contains select statement with @variables, but it says `View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`

Answer (score 9):

I think you cannot do that.

As from the MYSQL [guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html):

> A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> [ deletia ]
>
> The [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement cannot refer to system or user variables.

Comment: Is there an alternative to VIEW?

Answer (score 5):

Views are select statements, nothing more.  Views can not be multiple statements.  If you can't get this view down to a single statement, try the suggestion [here](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/mysql-stored-function-that-returns-table/) to use a function or procedure.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number) suggestion for MYSQL using a join instead of a set.

```
JOIN    (SELECT @rank:= 0) r;
```

Here is a untested example, I am not sure if you can order by '#' at the end, but if you can it would sort everything correctly by rank:

```
CREATE VIEW S1_Bottom_Performer_AHT as (
SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS '#', *
FROM
(SELECT         ei.SM,
                ei.TM,
                es.Month_Date,
                ei.emp_id,
                ei.DNAME,
                ei.STATUS,
                ei.SHIFT,
                ei.SKILL,
                ei.HIRE_DATE,
                ifnull(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ei.HIRE_DATE, now()), '-') AS Tenure,
                ifnull(es.Call_Handled, '-') AS Call_Handled,
                ifnull(es.AHT, '-') AS AHT
FROM mtl_extended_info ei
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT es.Employee_ID,
           es.Month_Date,
           sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct) AS Call_Handled,
           round((sum(es.I_Talk_Time_Sec) + sum(es.Hold_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_Work_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) AS AHT
   FROM cdl_agent_call_voume_gen es
   WHERE es.Month_Date = '2013-09-01'
   GROUP BY es.Employee_ID,
            es.Month_Date ) es ON es.Employee_ID = ei.emp_id
WHERE es.Month_Date = '2013-09-01'
  AND ei.Visible = 1
  AND ei.SKILL != 'RSD'
GROUP BY ei.emp_id
ORDER BY es.AHT DESC LIMIT 80)
) AS RESULTS
JOIN    (SELECT @rank:= 0) r; 
ORDER BY '#'
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not giving me the number in order. it starts at 58 and then 5, 8 etc...

Comment: Do note that you have GROUP BY ei.emp_id
ORDER BY es.AHT DESC LIMIT 80);  This can mess up your rank ordering.  I might try making your current select a sub query, taking the rank out of it, then making an outer select that selects from your current query and adds on the rank to your final result set.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ChongGuan Edited my answer.  I can't test it but hopefully it is close enough to give you a start.

Comment: It's giving me the follow error: `#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`

Comment: Which version of mysql allows to create a view with variables?