# Is there a simple way join rows by their row number in mysql?

Tags: mysql

So, I have two tables, the first has e.g. 4 records, and the second one contains e.g. two rows. They are not related in any way, just want them to be shown together in a way shown on the picture.[image]
I know it could be done by joining them by calculating their row number and using those, but I am curious if is there a way to do the same thing without using a variable. Thank you for your advise, and sorry for my english :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number. Numbering the rows like that, then JOINing on the new column *might* work.

Comment: They're not related in any way, yet you want to join them together?  What does that even mean?  Leaving databases aside for a moment, how can one ever "join" unrelated data?  It's nonsensical.  It's like asking how to breed a dog with an asteroid.  Also, be aware that (unless you explicitly specify an ordering), tables are *unordered*; therefore it is not defined which record is "first" and your problem as described is also undefined.  Besides all of which, to me the `DEPTNO` columns in your tables look suspiciously like a relationship on which they should be joined.

Comment: You are right, I am a stupid ass :) Of course they are related, both of them reference a third table. And sorry for the misleading picture above, thats only a (wrong) sample. Thanx

Comment: No, you're not a stupid ass, @eggyal is clearly an engineer who in 2013 lacked imagination of the real world. A very simple example is displaying two unrelated query results in the same table to the end user. E.g. a dataclip on heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it without using variables, just stright SQL
See this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eeb2/4

Unfortunately, MySql doesn't implement analytic functions like Oracle, Postgre and MS-SQL: 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ... order by ... )` nor `rownum` pseudocolumn like Oracle, and a performace of queries like this in MySql is very poor.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT emp.*,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM emp e
        WHERE e.empno <= emp.empno
        ) rownum
  FROM emp
) e
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT dept.*,
         (SELECT count(*)
          FROM dept d
          WHERE d.deptno <= dept.deptno
          ) rownum
   FROM dept
) d
ON e.rownum = d.rownum;
```