# how do I get the ordinal position of a record returned by mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have PHP code that goes out and gets a record from a database table.

This post was marked as duplicated so I tried the answer at [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number) and as expected it gave me ordinal position of 1, when the ordinal position of the record is actually 19782. This link gives the row number based on the returned results, my question differs because I am looking of the ordinal position of a single returned record based on the entire table.  Which I stated twice in the original post.

```
$query-'SELECT * FROM ' . $datafile .  ' WHERE ' . $seekindex . ' = "' $seekdata . '" ORDER BY ' . $fieldname;
```

Where:
datafile is any valid table from the currently open database.
seekindex is any column name from the table.
seekdata is given by the user.
fieldname is any column name form the table.

The query works fine and returns the record(s) it was ask to return.  I would like to know the ordinal position of that record in datafile if all records were selected ordering by fieldname.  I need to scroll down 1 to 10 records at a time ordering on fieldname.  I could then use a simple query such as:

```
$rn=mysql_result($result, 0, 'rownum'); // or what ever would give me the ordinal position.
$rn10=$rn+10;
$query='SELECT * FROM ' . $datafile . ' ORDER BY ' . $fieldname  . ' LIMIT ' $rn .','. $rn10;
```

There may be more than one record that meets the original query, A good example would be a zip code table where the user may be looking for the zip for a city near them and they type in theirs and want to scroll down till they find the city they are looking for.  If there are 20 records that meet the same criteria and I get the next 10 records I will never move if I just use.

```
$query-'SELECT * FROM ' . $datafile .  ' WHERE ' . $seekindex . ' >= "' $seekdata . '" ORDER BY ' . $fieldname . ' LIMIT 1,11;
```

In addition there may or may not be a unique field or ID in the table.  I always use them but in this case I was not the creator of the tables.

I tried get all of the records and sort through until I find the one I have selected but some of the candidates for datafile have over 200K records so that became impractical for a dynamic search, waiting over 2 minutes for a page down to take effect.

Is there a way to get the ordinal position of a single record based on all of the records for a given ORDER BY?  Or is there another way that I can't see because I am so determined to make this work?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `LIMIT 0, 10` the first time, `LIMIT 10, 10` the second time, and so on?

Comment: Barmar, I may be starting in the middle of the table.  for instance the user puts in the zip code 34543, that would be my starting point.  I would use the position from there.  I guess I could arbitrarily set that to zero and use >= or <= and limit 0,10. ASC or DESC.

Comment: Where has this question been ask and answered before.  I have been searching for quite some time to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own ordinal pretty easily

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Do your stuff here
    $counter++;
}
```

This is practical for things like [mysql_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), where you have to provide a record position.

Last but not least, please stop using `mysql_query` and the associated functions. They are [depreciated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).