# How to search for a specific value within a SQL result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a SQL database with the following structure and information:

```
idClub   Pts   GD
1        3      2
2        4      0
3        5     -1
4        0     -3
5        9      5
6        1      2
7        3      1
8        0     -2
9        6      0
10       7      5
```

If if do:

> $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Pts Desc, GD
>   Desc");

It will deliver this:

```
idClub   Pts   GD
5        9      5    //Row Number = 1
10       7      5    //Row Number = 2
9        6      0    //Row Number = 3
3        5     -1    //Row Number = 4
2        4      0    //Row Number = 5
1        3      2    //Row Number = 6
7        3      1    //Row Number = 7
6        1      2    //Row Number = 8
8        0     -2    //Row Number = 9
4        0     -3    //Row Number = 10
```

Each idClub has its own profile page - profile.php?Id=X - in which I need to show the club with the id but also the 2 teams that are above and below in the table.

Is there any way of knowing the row number (position) of a given value in a $result?
For example, profile.php?Id=3 it will be 4; for profile.php?Id=1 it will be 6, and so on..

For instance, for profile.php?Id=3 I need a $result that delivers the following:

```
idClub   Pts   GD
10       7      5
9        6      0
3        5     -1
2        4      0
1        3      2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might try this previous question [how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take your present query,

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  atable
ORDER BY
  Pts DESC,
  GD DESC
```

and add row numbering to it using a well-known technique that involves variable assignment:

```sql
SELECT
  atable.*,
  @row := @row + 1 AS row
FROM
  atable
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT @row := 0) AS p
ORDER BY
  Pts DESC,
  GD DESC
```

This will assign rankings to your rows according to the specified order. Now, if we knew the row number associated with the specified `idClub`, we'd just use the above query as a derived table and filter its result set on the condition of

```sql
WHERE
  row BETWEEN @idXrow - 2 AND @idXrow + 2
```

And we *can* find out that `@idXrow` value. For that, we can add one more variable assignment to the subquery:

```sql
@idXrow := CASE idClub WHEN 3 THEN @row ELSE @idXrow END
```

where `3` is the specified `idClub` value – in your final query it might need to be replaced with a parameter reference. Anyway, the [complete query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/106764/1) to do the job would look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  row,
  idClub,
  Pts,
  GD
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      atable.*,
      @row := @row + 1 AS row,
      @idXrow := CASE idClub WHEN 3 THEN @row ELSE @idXrow END
    FROM
      atable
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @row := 0) AS p
    ORDER BY
      Pts DESC,
      GD DESC
  ) AS s
WHERE
  row BETWEEN @idXrow - 2 AND @idXrow + 2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about just the query in `$result`, you can keep track of a variable that is iterated in your print loop like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Pts Desc, GD Desc");
$c = 0;

echo "<table>\n<tr>\n<td>idClub</td>\n<td>Pts</td>\n<td>GD</td>\n<td>Row #</td>\n</tr>\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>\n<td>$row[idClub]</td>\n<td>$row[Pts]</td>\n<td>$row[GD]</td>\n<td>$c</td>\n</tr>\n";
    $c++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: But in this "echo" the complete table will be printed (rows 1 to 10). What I need is (for example for profile.php?id=3) to print only rows 2 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
$selClub = $_GET["Id"];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT idClub FROM table");
for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->num_rows; $i++) {
    if ( $result->fetch_object()->idClub == $selClub )
        $position = $i;
}

if ( $position <= 2 ) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Pts Desc, GD Desc LIMIT 0, 5");
} elseif ( $position >= $result->num_rows - 1 ) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Pts Desc, GD Desc LIMIT ($result->num_rows-5), 5");
} else {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Pts Desc, GD Desc LIMIT ($position-3), 5");
}
```

Is it actually a problem to use the same name for the first and second $result?