# How to show rank using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
user_id | date | point
    1      20      4
    2      20      3
    3      20      2
    1      21      1
    2      21      3
    3      21      5
    1      23      2
    2      23      4
    3      23      5
```

And query:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS point, @row:=@row+1 rank FROM users GROUP BY user_id
```

How to show rank in this query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table

Answer (score 2):

first you need to delcare @row as variable first

Something like `set @row=0; select user_id,SUM(point) as point,@row := @row + 1 as rank from users GROUP BY user_id  order by SUM(point) desc;`

Comment: select `user_id` not `userid`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SET @row=0;
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS point, @row:=@row+1 rank FROM users GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the declaring part using this way:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS point, @row:=@row+1 rank FROM users, (SELECT @row := 0) r GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've to write it like:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS point, @row:=@row+1 AS rank FROM users GROUP BY user_id JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT user_id,points, @row:=@row+1 AS Row 
from (
  SELECT user_id, 
    SUM(point) AS points  rank 
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY user_id 
  Sort by points);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have an AS to alias @row to rank, and an order by on point to get them in the right order to rank:-

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS point, @row:=@row+1 AS rank 
FROM users 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row:=0) Sub1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY point DESC
```