# mysql show position in resultset

Tags: mysql

So I have a list of say 10 rows. Each with an key and value.

Is there a way in mysql where I can, get a rows position in a given resultset:

```
SELECT 'resultSetPosition' FROM table WHERE rowKey=x ORDER BY rowValue

id        value
 1        a
 2        b
 3        c

 o/p required

 if  id 3 the i need to get position of that row is 3
```

EDIT: I only want to get one row out in my resultset, but the 'position' should relate to its position for example if you sort by id.

(Obviously this whole thing is easy if I just pull the entire resultset and search the array in my programming, but I wanted to see if it could be done in mysql alone.)

Comment: can you make more specific your question/

Comment: possible duplicate of [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table)

Comment: Try looking at this answer that looks similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4474389/1418400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM TABLE
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) R;
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS resultSetPosition
 FROM tableName
 WHERE rowKey=x
 ORDER BY rowValue
```

Also take a look at [this link](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this hope this will clear your problem

```
 select count(*) as pos from table_name where id<=current_id
```