# how to SELECT numbering column AFTER order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do a MySQL statement that gives off a numbering column based on the ordered criteria? For example, with the use of variables I have been able to produce such column, but the numbering process occurs before it is ordered so the results look in return... out of order

Comment: This question lacks sufficient detail.  Please post the query, desired results, and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a counter:

```
    SELECT  t.field, t.fieldbis 
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
    FROM    table l
    JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
    WHERE   t.field > 50
    ORDER BY t.field2
```

See [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table)