# how to sort data and then number the rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

there's table with rows, for example:

```
+----+
|num |
+----+
| 6  |   
| 10 |
| 3  |
+----+
```

I try to sort descending and then number the rows

```
select num, @c:=@c+1 as c from table1 order by num desc;
```

but it's not exactly what I need. Is there any possibility to get table below?

```
+----+----+
|num |  c |
+----+----+
| 10 |  1 |
| 6  |  2 |
| 3  |  3 |
+----+----+
```

Comment: When you sort the data with `num` and there is no other values with the same `num` then sorting with row number will not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum:=0;

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, num
             *
      FROM (Select num from table1 order by num desc))
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table)

You have to initialize the row count variabele:

```
SELECT num, @c := @c + 1 AS row_number FROM test_table JOIN (SELECT @c := 0) c ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Test set:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`num`) VALUES (6), (10), (3);
```