# How to get row number using sql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables. one is local and other one is foreign. so what I want to do is to give row numbers after joining two tables using stored procedure. 
First I want to get same number of column from two tables and after that I want combine as a one table and give row numbers.
below is my query.

```
set @row_number=0;

select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as number, 
(
select a.*
from 
(select ID,title,last_name,first_name
from local
)
a
union all
select b.*
from
(select ID,title ,last_name,first_name
from foreign
)
b
)
;
```

Could anyone please tell me what the wrong with it?

Comment: It's either MySQL or SQL Server. These are completely different products. Which one are you asking about?  SQL Server has ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`. MySQL doesn't. MySQL doesn't have most of the ranking, windowing and analytic functions offered by other databases

Comment: Why do people mark questions with both MySQL and SQL Server tags when clearly they want an answer for only *one* of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - May be its because the syntax belongs to `Mysql` and they want equivalent in `Sql server`

Comment: There are far, far too many questions mislabeled as both `MySQL` and `sql-server`. I really want to know why so we can clean up the questions. A mislabeled questions usually gets downvoted and closed as unclear in minutes

Comment: That is my misunderstanding with tags because I am a newbie to stackoverflow. thnks @panagiotis for mentioning about tags. Now I am careful with tags when I am going to post a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using MySQL, not SQL Server, and try to emulate row numbers, as shown eg [in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/with-mysql-how-can-i-generate-a-column-containing-the-record-index-in-a-table). This is trivial to do in SQL Server using the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, as shown by @Prdp's answer.

MySQL though doesn't have the ranking, analytic or windowing functions found in other databases. Such functions can be emulated in a very limited fashion by using non-standard SQL tricks, as shown in the linked question.

Such tricks are very limited though. A typical use of `ROW_NUMBER` is to rank records inside a group, eg top 10 salesmen by region. It's not possible to do that with the  `@curRow := @curRow + 1` trick. There are performance implications as well. This trick will *only* work if the rows are processed sequentially.

In the question's case, a MySQL query would probably look like this:

```
SELECT  l.ID,
        l.title,
        l.last_name,
        l.first_name,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    (   select ID,title,last_name,first_name
            from local
            UNION ALL
            select ID,title ,last_name,first_name
            from foreign
         ) l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
```

The trick here is that `JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0)` creates the variable  `@curRow` with an initial value of 0 and returns its value. The database will take the query results and for each row, it will increase the variable and return the increased value. This can only be done at the end and forces sequential processing of the results.

By using `JOIN (SELECT @curRow :=0) r` you just avoid creating the variable in a separate statement.

Comment: thnks a lot @Panagiotis. your answer helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in `SQL SERVER`

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER(
           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))AS number,a.*
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               title,
               last_name,
               first_name
        FROM   local
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID,
               title,
               last_name,
               first_name
        FROM   FOREIGN) a
```

**Note :** replace `(SELECT NULL)` with the column you want order by row number generation. Now the row number generation is arbitrary

Comment: A Row number is pretty useless without actual ordering, unless it's only meant for non-significant labelling (ie if you don't actually care about the numbers). The value will change randomly each time the query is executed, either due to parallel execution, or a changing execution plan.

Comment: Thanks @Prdp . what are the changes if we use mysql?

Comment: @MadhushaPerera - You want answer for `Mysql` or `Sql server`

Comment: @MadhushaPerera MySQL and SQL Server are completely different. Besides, this question has *already* been answered for MySQL by the duplicate question. Using the *correct* tags means that you'll get an answer a lot faster