# SAP HANA: days between two Orders

Tags: mysql, sql, hana

Here is the table ihave, i was trying days between by joining the same table with  left join and group by with min difference. I was not so successful.

```
 Customer|Order|Date
    1    | 1   |Date1
    1    | 2   |Date2
    1    | 3   |Date3
    1    | 4   |Date4
    2    | 1   |Date1
    2    | 2   |Date3
    2    | 3   |Date6
    3    | 1   |Date3
    3    | 2   |Date5
```

Required is:

```
 Customer|Order|Date |diff
    1    | 1   |Date1| 0
    1    | 2   |Date2| days_betwen(Date2, Date1)
    1    | 3   |Date3| days_betwen(Date3, Date2)
    1    | 4   |Date4| days_betwen(Date4, Date3)
    2    | 1   |Date1| 0
    2    | 2   |Date3| days_betwen(Date3, Date1)
    2    | 3   |Date6| days_betwen(Date6, Date3)
    3    | 1   |Date3| 0
    3    | 2   |Date5| days_betwen(Date5, Date3)
```

I need suggestion with the logic part!

**EDIT:** What if the order numbers are not sequential?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry thanks!  Would follow the three steps from my next question on wards.

Comment: I fear that may be very, very soon

Comment: What do you mean by `that`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first, you need to join the table to itself by `Customer` and `Order` fields. Then use [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to get days number between two dates.

1. If the `Order` column is numbered sequentially then solution is simplest:

   ```
   SELECT 
     cur.`Customer` AS `Customer`,
     cur.`Order` AS `Order`, 
     cur.`Date` AS `Date`, 
     DATEDIFF(cur.`Date`, IFNULL(prv.`Date`, cur.`Date`)) AS `DaysPassed`
   FROM 
     MyTable cur
     LEFT JOIN 
     MyTable prv
     ON cur.`Customer` = prv.`Customer` AND cur.`Order` = prv.`Order`+ 1;
   ```
2. If the `Order` column is not numbered sequentially, but next `Order` value is greater than previous, then you could use *greater than* or *less than* operators. Use `GROUP BY` clause and an aggregate function to return single row for each order. Note, maybe it will be long!

   ```
   SELECT 
       comb.`Customer` AS `Customer`,
       comb.`curOrder` AS `Order`, 
       comb.`curDate` AS `Date`, 
       DATEDIFF(comb.`curDate`, IFNULL(pr.`Date`, comb.`curDate`)) AS `DaysPassed`
   FROM
       (SELECT 
         cur.`Customer` AS `Customer`, cur.`Order` AS curOrder, cur.`curDate` AS `Date`, max(prv.`Order`) AS `prvOrder`
       FROM 
         MyTable cur
         LEFT JOIN 
         MyTable prv
         ON cur.`Customer` = prv.`Customer` AND cur.`Order` > prv.`Order`
         GROUP BY cur.`Order`, cur.`Customer`) comb
       LEFT JOIN
       MyTable pr 
       ON pr.`Customer` = comb.`Customer` AND pr.`Order` = comb.prvOrder;
   ```
3. If you use random order number, then it is possible to use `Date` column instead of `Order` in the `comb` subquery to join records by nearest order dates of same customer.

Good luck!

Comment: that was very clever and neat! what if the order numbers are not sequential?

Comment: @Sai, then it will be difficult! You could try to use [temporary variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127004/7914637) to index rows. But I am not sure that it will be used in JOIN clause.

Comment: That was exactly i was thinking after your very smart solution. I will have to check it on Monday! I will leave you a message after checking. Thank for the cool Idea.

Comment: Hello, @Sai! Was your trouble solved? I have added a few suggestions to my answer. Please, write what will have been helpfull for you.

Comment: Hi, I haven't got the opportunity yet to try, i hope i will be at my workstation tomorrow. The solution you have provided now, was the similar that i have tried. As your previous suggestion was very cool, i was thinking of using `rownumber() partition over order` and use the cool join logic. Nevertheless i will try both once i am at my workstation. Thanks Mate!

Comment: you have to excuse me for not updating you, i havent checked it out yet.