# MySQL cannot use ":=" in SSRS

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to assign an index to each row of the query result, I am following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127004/4541141) to achieve that.

This index number is not for displaying purpose, if it is only for displaying, using `RowNumber()` in SSRS is enough. Instead, I will be using that index number for filtering purpose. Please also note that SSRS cannot use `RowNumber()` in Filter Expression.

For example, I want the results with index < 10 to be displayed in tablix 1, index >= 10 will be displayed in tablix 2, something like that.

My query works fine in MySQL, until I run it with SSRS, it comes out the error. Looks like SSRS does not support the `:=` operator in `@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number`. If I remove the colon `:` from the operator, the error gone, but row number does not increment.

Why SSRS does not support the `:=` operator?  is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this case from [here](https://datamakessense.com/mysql-rownum-row-number-function/)

> **DISCLAIMER:**
>
> 1. Does not work on older versions of mySQL It is based on using
>      variables that only reset when time changes.
> 2. If the function is invoked in 2 separate places in the same
>      microsecond(1 millionth of a second), the output will not be as
>      expected. The variable will not reset, the output will not start
>      counting from 1.
> 3. If you run the function more than once in the same query, it will
>      increment every time it is run, so possibly multiple times per row.

The workaround is to create a MySQL function to generate the row number:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS rownum;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION rownum()
  RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  set @prvrownum=if(@ranklastrun=CURTIME(6),@prvrownum+1,1);
  set @ranklastrun=CURTIME(6);
  RETURN @prvrownum;
END $$
$$
DELIMITER ;
```